# Pixel art not drawing properly on screen when in motion

Tags: libgdx

[When camera zoom is 1f](https://vimeo.com/715030187)

[When camera zoom is 1.31f](https://vimeo.com/715030586) (view is distorted)

The reason it's like this is because I'm using the nearest filter. I have to use nearest filter for pixel art.

I want the map to look properly at different zooms.

in first video, 1 unit equals 4 pixels(world is 320x180, screen is 1280x720) and there is no problem as there is integer scaling.
but since I use zoom it is not possible to always keep the scale at the integer number.

Any ideas on how to properly draw pixel art with libgdx?